# Copy a vector to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I copied a 2dim array into a 2dim vector and I did some modifications on it, now i want to know how can I copy a 2dim vector into a 2dim array?(I did as below:)

Copy an 2dim array to 2dim vector:

```
vector< vector<int>> path2;
 vector<int> temp; // For simplicity
 for (int x = 0; x <= 1; x++)
{temp.clear();
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        temp.push_back(path1[x][y]);
    }
    path2.push_back(temp);

}
```

out put:

```
path2[0][6,0,2,6]
path2[1][6,1,3,6]
```

Copy the 2dim vector to 2dim array

```
int arr [4][10] ;
 copy(path3.begin(), path3.end(), arr);
```

print the arr

```
 for (int i=0;i< ???? ;i++)// how to define size of the vector first dimention which is 2 ( i am aware about size() for 1 dim vector, but for 2dim vector ...... ??????????
     for(int j=0;j<?????; j++) //same prolem as above
         cout<<endl<<arr[i][j];
```

The problem is i am not sure about the copy part and and i dont know how to define the size of each size of vector?

Comment: Time to step back and determine some answers.  A vector is randomly accessible with the `[]` operator, along with many other features and built in member functions.  What is the reason to convert back to a more basic array, when you can print the vector contents with iterators and/or using the `size` member function as needed / desired?  Even the C++11 `range for` and `auto` keyword can be used if the compiler in use supports the C++11 standard.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD to be fair even C-style arrays can be used in `range for` loops.

Comment: @Jefffrey doesnt range-based for require begin() and end()

Comment: @Paranaix std::begin() and std::end() work with C-style arrays.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD let me change my question , how can i determine the size of each dimension of the vector ? (should i use size()or something else and how)

Comment: @Paranaix: The definition of "range for" semantics explicitly says how to handle an array type.  (Plus, there are `std::begin` and `std::end` overloads that work with arrays, which might or might not be included.)

Comment: I would change `path2.push_back(temp);` to `path2.push_back(std::move(temp));`.

Comment: Unless something has radically changed over the past 17 years, `std::vector::size()` runs in constant time.  The last sample @user3493289 has written in the answer below uses the `size()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do any of these to iterate over a vector of vector:

```
//Works for C++11
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
for(auto &i : vec)
   for(auto &j : i)
      std::cout << j << std::endl;

//Works for C++11
for (auto iter = vec.cbegin(); iter != vec.cend(); ++iter)
    for(auto sub_iter = iter->cbegin(); sub_iter != iter->cend(); ++sub_iter)
       std::cout << *sub_iter << std::endl;

//Works for C++03 and C++11
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator Iter;
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator Sub_Iter;
for (Iter iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
    for(Sub_Iter sub_iter = iter->begin(); sub_iter != iter->end(); ++sub_iter)
       std::cout << *sub_iter << std::endl;


//works for C++03 and C++11
for(int i = 0; i<vec.size(); ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); ++j)
       std::cout << vec[i][j] << std::endl;
```